# Expected type 'int', got 'IntegerField' instead Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get an object of class Guide to be the value of a calculation of other objects in the class.
This is how far I have got in my code but got error

```
Expected type 'int', got 'IntegerField' instead.
```

How do I get this to work?

Here is my code:

```
class Guide(models.Model): 
    guide_title = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    guide_category = models.CharField(max_length=70) 
    guide_why = models.TextField() 
    guide_how = models.TextField() 
    user_current_conversion_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    user_optimal_conversion_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    user_monthly_visitors = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_average_order_value = models.IntegerField(default=0) 
    user_increase_conversion_rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def user_increase_conversion_rate(self):
        return int(
           (self.user_monthly_visitors*(self.user_optimal_conversion_rate/100))*
            self.user_average_order_value) -
            ((self.user_monthly_visitors*(self.user_current_conversion_rate/100))*
            self.user_average_order_value)
```

Comment: Could you show your models?

Comment: post the models code too for the class you are using this property

Comment: Please post the full error so we know what line the error is on.

Comment: Huh?  IntegerField is a model field.  Int is a primitive type.

Comment: update question instead of pasting model in comment.

Comment: I get error in the @property in all the self.user (Expected int)

Comment: what values are you posting??

Comment: I am posting the value of user_increase_conversion_rate

Comment: then how the other fileds will get the value for the calculation?? what you are doing is simply passing the fields and not its values

Comment: The values is saved in the database. Got it created by admin.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same name - `user_increase_conversion_rate` - for your property and a model field.

Comment: Okey thanks. Should I remove the object user_increase_conversion_rate? And only use the property?

Comment: @9minday what you should do is __rename__ one or the other - you cannot have two attributes by the same name in a class statement.

Comment: Okey thanks. I only need it to display the value of the math formula in the html template. Which attribute should I use in the template?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do handling on a field via `@property`, you can change the field name to add an underscore (by convention) and then write property getter and setter methods. That way Django cleanly knows how to set the field, and you get control over how it gets set.

See:

https://www.stavros.io/posts/how-replace-django-model-field-property/